# How do I set the width of a drop down based on the width of the clicked item

Tags: jquery

I would like to set the width of a dropdown to the width of the link clicked. This must be generic, not based on IDs, as there may be many of these on a page. Here is my markup:

```
  <div class="dropdown bottom clearfix">
    <a class="nav toolbar-nav dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><h2 class="nav">Clickable Item</h2></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-bottom-right clearfix"  role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a>Item One</a></li>
      <li><a>Item Two</a></li>
      <li><a>Item Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I am using bootstrap by the way.

Comment: Can you post the drop down markup?

Comment: Dropdown markup is in there, see <ul>...</ul>

Comment: By drop down I thought you meant a select.

Comment: Sorry, Bootstrap dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just use the $.width() jquery method. You can call all the items on the page and format their respective lists using the $.each() method.

jQuery:

```
$(".nav").each(function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    $(this + "li").css("width", width);
});
```

The ".nav" can be replaced by "h2" or "a" if you are only using those DOM elements for clickable items, leaving open the tags for formatting.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. Let me update this fiddle for width.